# How I can access the data from a popup page with watir?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

I want to access the data in a popup window containing a login form, this window opens when you click on a logo, this line contains the code to execute the javascript: `<div id="loadDIV" class="containerLogo" onclick="ventanaSecundaria('/Security-war/autentia/Login.jsp?sion=c5ac379249711c18cf6e030c8400',800,600); "></div>`

with this line run the script:
`browser = browser.div(:class => "containerLogo").fire_event :click`
watir open in a new popup form.
The problem is that I can not access the data from the popup window and need to fill the form containing, try the following:`puts browser.text.include? 'Login'`
and get false, then I thought that maybe I could not access the other popup and look for something to not open another window but only refresh the I'm using and so we can access its contents, looking I found that I can do this:
`browser.goto("javascript:document.getElementByClass()'containerLogo').click()")`
but I try to console returns 'true' and the browser does not update.

**Update**
You can switch windows simply with this:
`browser.window(:index => 1).use`

and to be sure we change verify the url window with this:

```
browser.window.url
```

Answer (score 0):

> When a new browser window is opened, you can then ‘use’ the new
>   window. [[Browser Popups | Watir Webdriver]](http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-popups/)

```
browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.button(:id => "close").click
end
```